# Correct way of iterating over pandas dataframe by date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I want to iterate over a dataframe's major axis date by date.

**Example:**

`tdf = df.ix[date]`

The issue I am having is that the type returned by `df.ix` changes, leaving me with 3 possible situations

1. If the date does not exist in `tdf` an error is thrown: `KeyError: 1394755200000000000`
2. If there is only one item in `tdf`: `print type(tdf)` returns
   `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`
3. If there is more than one item in `tdf`: `print type(tdf)` returns
   `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

To avoid the first case I can simply wrap this in a `try catch` block or thanks to jxstanford, I can avoid the try catch block by using `if date in df.index:`

I run into the issue afterwards with an inconsistent API with a pandas series and a pandas data frame. I could solve this by checking for types but it seems I shouldn't have to do that. I would ideally like to keep the types the same. Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm running pandas 0.13.1 and I am currently loading my data from a CSV using

Here's a full example demonstrating the problem.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime

path_to_csv = '/home/n/Documents/port/test.csv'

df = DataFrame.from_csv(path_to_csv, index_col=3, header=0, parse_dates=True, sep=',')

start_dt = df.index.min()
end_dt = df.index.max()
dt_step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)

cur_dt = start_dt

while cur_dt != end_dt:
    if cur_dt in df.index:
       print type(df.ix[cur_dt])
    #run some other steps using cur_dt

    cur_dt += dt_step
```

An example CSV that demonstrates the problem is as follows:

```
value1,value2,value3,Date,type
1,2,4,03/13/14,a
2,3,3,03/21/14,b
3,4,2,03/21/14,a
4,5,1,03/27/14,b
```

The above code prints out

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Is it possible to get the value of `value1` from tdf in a consistent manner? or am I stuck making an if statement for and separately handle each case?

```
if type(df.ix[cur_dt]) == DataFrame:
    ....
if type(df.ix[cur_dt]) == Series:
    ....
```

Comment: Well you could get a unique list of all the dates using `unique` and then iterate over the list.

Comment: @KarlD. I need all the dates for other things, not just the unique values in the dataframe many dates are missing.

Comment: Try using DataFrame.from_csv instead of pandas.read_csv.  This may help with your issues 2 and 3.

Comment: You really have to provide more detail, a toy dataset for starters. The behaviour you are getting is expected: if you extract one row, you get a Series (a one dimension array), if you extract more than one row, it is a DataFrame (two dimension array). And if you tell pandas to look for something that isn't there, it gives you an error. There are methods to deal with all of that if you explain what you want as a result (A column? More columns?).

Comment: @jxstanford thanks I tried your suggestion I still get the same problem,

Comment: @dmvianna I added a complete example, if this is expected what is the recommended way of dealing with this? Make two separate `if type(df.ix[cur_dt]) == DataFrame:` and `if type(df.ix[cur_dt]) == Series:` to take care of both cases?

Comment: I think you want to use the `apply` method of the **DataFrame**, using axis = 1, e.g. df.apply(lambda row: print row, axis=1).  This method will generate a series, which you could add to your **DataFrame**.  I'll write this up into an answer for you.

Comment: How would you handle duplicate dates? Drop them? Add the values? Get the means? Or would you prefer to get single rows as dataframes? Series has a .to_frame() method, so that can be done. Also, do you want to interpolate missing dates or ignore them?

Comment: @dmvianna for duplicate values I was hoping to just use a for each loop and process each value, missing dates I use else where outside of the first if statement

Comment: Do you need to extract values at all? Why don't you just use df.apply and process each row separately?

Comment: @dmvianna I need to do other steps for each date as well

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain it. So far, from what you explained, nothing prevents you from running df.apply for each step, or using it once with a function that will handle all steps.

Comment: @dmvianna at each date (including the dates not in the df) I need to run other calculations using the date in the loop. So at each iteration process the dataframe for values on the current date, then use that same date for other operations then goto next date until finished with the while loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51788/discussion-between-dmvianna-and-pycthon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This toy code will return DataFrames consistently.

```
def framer(rows):
    if ndim(rows) == 1:
        return rows.to_frame().T
    else:
        return rows

for cur_date in df.index:
    print type(framer(df.ix[cur_date]))
```

And this will give you the missing days:

```
df.resample(rule='D')
```

Have a look at the resample method docstring. It has its own options to fill up the missing data. And if you decide to make your multiple dates into a single one, the method you're looking at is **groupby** (if you want to combine values across rows) and **drop_duplicates** (if you want to ignore them). There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your trying to do with the dataframe, but this might be better than a try/except:

```
tdf = DataFrame.from_csv(path_to_csv, index_col=3, header=0, parse_dates=True, sep=',')
while cur_dt != end_dt:
    if cur_dt in df.index:
       # do your thing

    cur_dt += dt_step
```

Comment: This does help! but i run into other issues I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` method of the **DataFrame**, using `axis = 1` to work on each row of the **DataFrame** to build a **Series** with the same **Index**.

e.g.

```
def calculate_value(row):
   if row.date == pd.datetime(2014,3,21):
      return 0
   elif row.type == 'a':
      return row.value1 + row.value2 + row.value3
   else:
      return row.value1 * row.value2 * row.value3

df['date'] = df.index
df['NewValue'] = df.apply(calculate_value, axis=1)
```

modifies your example input as follows

```
            value1  value2  value3 type  NewValue       date
Date
2014-03-13       1       2       4    a         7 2014-03-13
2014-03-21       2       3       3    b         0 2014-03-21
2014-03-21       3       4       2    a         0 2014-03-21
2014-03-27       4       5       1    b        20 2014-03-27

[4 rows x 6 columns]
```